# Using C# dll functions in matlab code

Tags: c#, matlab, .net-assembly

I have a C# project, and I want to use the function of my project in matlab.
I've added

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
```

befor every classes in my project and make the out put type class library.
but when I use of dll in matlab,

```
temp = NET.addAssembly('../../foo')
```

and then `foo.Classes`, there is no class!
what should i do?! plz help me :)

Comment: It is not necessary to make your class COM visible to use `NET.addAssembly` but your class just need at least to be `public`

Comment: hmm, tnQ. but now I cant access to the methods!

Comment: Well, the methods you want to access have to be `public` too ...

Comment: See sample code in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sample regarding above comment*

To use a class from a .NET assembly using `NET.addAssembly(...)`, there is no need to make the class COM Visible but the class, *as well as the methods you want to access to*, have to be **public**.

**.NET code**

```
namespace foo
{   
    public class SampleClass
    {
        // Constructor
        public SampleClass() { }

        // Static example
        public static string StaticMethod() { return "Hello from static method."; }

        // Instance example
        public string InstanceMethod() { return "Hello from instance method."; }
    }
}
```

**Usage from Matlab**

```
% Loading the .NET assembly
NET.addAssembly('..\..\Foo.dll');

% Call of a static method
foo.SampleClass.StaticMethod()

% Call of an instance method
instance = foo.SampleClass();
instance.InstanceMethod();
```